# How to Create user in Sitecore User Manager using membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I created a user using `createuser()` in membership provider to specific role and domain. But in User Manager it Showing Message `data could not be loaded` and it is not showing the user created by me in the user manager list.

I get the users using `GetUsersInRole()` and binding users to grid control,users created by me was shown in the grid.

*Why it is not showing in user manager list; and how to solve this problem?*

Comment: Can you post membership configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Please check next code to add a user :

```
 public void AddUser(string domain, string firstName, string lastName, string email,string comment, string telephoneNumber, string jobTitle)
    {
        string userName = string.Concat(firstName, lastName);
        userName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, userName);
      string newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 3);

         try
        {
            if (!User.Exists(userName))
            {
                Membership.CreateUser(userName, newPassword, email);

                // Edit the profile information
                Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(userName, true);
                Sitecore.Security.UserProfile userProfile = user.Profile;
                userProfile.FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
                userProfile.Comment = comment;

                // Assigning the user profile template
                userProfile.SetPropertyValue("ProfileItemId", "{AE4C4969-5B7E-4B4E-9042-B2D8701CE214}");

                // Have modified the user template to also contain telephone number and job title.
                userProfile.SetCustomProperty("TelephoneNumber", telephoneNumber);
                userProfile.SetCustomProperty("JobTitle", jobTitle);
                userProfile.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(string.Format("Error in Client.Project.Security.UserMaintenance (AddUser): Message: {0}; Source:{1}", ex.Message, ex.Source), this);
        }
    }
```

here

Comment: thank u i tried this still i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This code should work if you use this instead of `createUser()`:

```
var fullName = Context.Domain.GetFullName(model.Email);

var user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Create(fullName, model.Password);
user.Profile.Email = model.Email;

user.Profile.Save();
```